# Getting NoneType has no attribute with Singleton implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, singleton

I'm trying to implement Singleton design pattern in Python, but for some reason, I'm getting `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file'` exception, even though file property it's assigned from the first `Logger` creation.

Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from datetime import datetime as time

class Logger:
    ''' Singleton class '''
    _INSTANCE:Logger = None

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        if Logger._INSTANCE == None:
            self.file = open('./logfile.txt', 'a+')
            self._INSTANCE = self
    
    def log(self, message:str) -> None:
        ''' Send message to file '''
        Logger._INSTANCE.file.write(f'{time.now()}\t{message}\n')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        ''' Returns file content '''
        Logger._INSTANCIA.file.seek(0)
        return Logger._INSTANCE.file.read()

    def __del__(self) -> None:
        ''' Close file at the end '''
        Logger._INSTANCE.file.close()

# Test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Logger()
    a.log('Logging from A')
    b = Logger()
    b.log('Logging from B')
    c = Logger()
    c.log('Logging from C')

    print(a)
```

Strangely enough, the next code will work just fine (not mine)

```
from __future__ import annotations
#Singleton

class Logger:
  ''' Singleton class '''
  _INSTANCE:Logger = None
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    """Nothing"""
    if Logger._INSTANCE == None:
      self.file = open('./logfile.txt', 'a+')
      Logger._INSTANCE = self
  
  def log(self, msg:str) -> None:
    '''Writes to log'''
    Logger._INSTANCE.file.write(msg + '\n')
    
  def __del__(self) -> None:
      Logger._INSTANCE.file.close()

  def __str__(self) -> str:
    '''Returns file content'''
    Logger._INSTANCE.file.seek(0)
    return Logger._INSTANCE.file.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  a = Logger()
  a.log("a")
  b = Logger()
  b.log("b")
  c = Logger()
  c.log("c")
  print(c)
```

What could it possibly be? I honestly don't know what it's missing

Comment: Both of the options are not very well written. Basically yours is not working because you use self._INSTANCE, instead of Logger._INSTANCE. Using self set the value in the instance but does not modify the Class attribute Logger._INSTANCE. I will try to write a formal answer.

Comment: Sure, they're just exercises for design patterns, sorry for the poorly written code. Changing self._INSTANCE to Logger._INSTANCE was the answer, it was so simple, as always... Thanks Lucas.